# Como limitar a quantidade de caracteres que um input text atribui a outro em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, javascript-eventos

Caros, pesquisando a respeito da minha pergunta, encontrei algo semelhante no [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8545395/6419926), mas ainda não consegui limitar os caracteres que o input "Título" duplica no "Código do Material", mesmo eu atribuindo um `maxlength=20` nesse.

Para ficar mais claro, tenho dois inputs: o que é digitado no "Título" é duplicado no "Código do Material" com as devidas normalizações (i.e. conversão de espaços e remoção de caracteres). Entretanto, o campo "Código do Material" não pode ter mais de 20 caracteres (o que é ignorado durante a "duplicação").

Como proceder nesse caso?
Grato desde já!

*P.S.: Acredito que não deveria fazer isso, mas junto a essa questão, tenho outra dúvida a qual se alguém, porventura, puder me esclarecer, também será de grande ajuda: tem como fazer essa "duplicação" ocorrer apenas uma vez? Algo como um `onBlur` no qual se o usuário editar o campo "Código do Material" e vier a editar também o "Título", não ocorrerá mais interferências naquele, visto que esse pode ser editado pelo mesmo usuário.*

```js
document.getElementById('f_titulo').addEventListener('input', duplica);

function duplica() {
      const codigomaterial = document.getElementById('f_titulo').value;
      const codigoalterado = codigomaterial.normalize('NFD').replace(/([\u0300-\u036f]|[^_0-9a-zA-Z\s])/g, '').replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase();
      document.getElementById('f_cod').value = codigoalterado;
};
```

```html
<input id="f_titulo" type="text" maxlength="60" placeholder="Título">

<input id="f_cod" type="text" maxlength="20" placeholder="Código do Material" required>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use o método .substring()

Esse método permite que você pegue somente as primeiras 20 letras do input "Título", como? Diga a este método que você quer pegar desde a primeira letra que é o index 0 até a vigésima letra que é o index 19.

Dessa forma ele sempre pegará a substring do index 0 até o index 19, mesmo que a String do input seja menor, o método vai ignorar, e vai pegar até onde der.

```js
document.getElementById('f_titulo').addEventListener('input', duplica);

function duplica() {
      const codigomaterial = document.getElementById('f_titulo').value;
      const codigoalterado = codigomaterial.normalize('NFD').replace(/([\u0300-\u036f]|[^_0-9a-zA-Z\s])/g, '').replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase().substring(0, 19);
      document.getElementById('f_cod').value = codigoalterado;
};
```

```html
<input id="f_titulo" type="text" maxlength="60" placeholder="Título">

<input id="f_cod" type="text" maxlength="20" placeholder="Código do Material" required>
```

Comment: Muito bom, @Laks Castro! Obrigado, cara! Ajudou bastante!